# why there is no selection when I click F5 to run program in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

In the begin, for example, I'd like to run program by click F5, and there is a selection box on the top of vscode. However, maybe I click some errorly, it debug directly, and no selection here, and the terminal shows (base) in the front of result, why and how to correct to original setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to reset VS settings as follows:
Note: Please use save as to backup settings.json in case you have something that you may need to restore later.
DO NOT DELETE ANYTHING FROM YOUR "defaultSettings.json"

These instructions are only for clearing out everything except {
} within your user settings.json:

> The easiest way to reset VS Code
>   back to the default settings is to clear your user settings.json file
>   contents in the Settings editor. Delete everything between the two
>   curly braces, save the file, and VS Code will go back to using the
>   default values.[How can I reset my user settings?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

If following above does not resolve your issue, please consider adding a screenshot of the issue along with your posted question and/or add default settings.json, so it can be compared with a working default settings.json file for your assistance.